# Möbius Transformation Example

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm interested in the form of the Möbius transformation of the following mappings: $2i \rightarrow 0, -1 \rightarrow \infty, 0 \rightarrow -4i$. When I tried to solve the system of equations I had trouble to interpret the mapping $-1 \rightarrow \infty$. Could anybody give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is $z \mapsto \frac{az+b}{z+1}$

Comment: Still don't get it … then $az+b = -4i$, therefore $-4ia = b$. Then I have to eliminate $a$ somehow.

Comment: Use the fact that $2i$ maps to $0$, and $0$ to $-4i$.

Comment: So then $\frac{2ai-4ai}{2i+1}=0$ and therefore $2ai-4ai = -2ai = 0$, and then $a=0$?

Comment: No, because your reasoning $az+b=-4i$ is wrong: it's only true when $z=0$. The correct answer is $b=-4i$, and $a=2$.

Comment: Ah ups. Okay thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A mobius transformation may be given as a function
$$
f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz + d}
$$
with some niceness restrictions on $a, b, c, d$.

If we have $f(z_0) = \infty$, that means that $z_0$ is a root of the denominator. In other words, $cz_0 + d = 0$. In your case, that means that you want $c\cdot (-1) + d = 0$.

Comment: Does this imply that $a = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

When working with a Möbius transformation 
$$f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}
$$
you are allowed to do just a little bit of "infinity arithmetic". For example:
$$\frac{a \cdot \infty + b}{c \cdot \infty + d}=\frac{a}{c}
$$
which equals $\infty$ when $c=0$.

And then a simple computation gives
$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{da - b}{-cx+a}
$$
and so
$$f^{-1}(\infty) = \frac{d \cdot \infty - b}{-c \cdot \infty + a} = \frac{d}{-c}
$$
which, again, equals $\infty$ when $c=0$.

You can, of course, justify this bit of "infinity arithmetic" rigorously using limits.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with an alternate answer where you can easily get rid of the limits.
Let the transformation be 
$w= \frac{az+b}{cz+d} $. Now substitute the corresponding values of $z$ and $w$. Now  you will get three equation as follows:

$0=\frac{2ai+b}{2ci+d},
\infty =\frac{-a+b}{-c+d} $ ..We get $-c+d =0$
And the equation is $b=-4id$

Now solve for $a,b,c,d$. We get 
 $a=\frac{b}{(2/i)}= \frac{c}{(1/2)}=\frac{d}{(1/2)} $.
Put these values of $a,b,c,d$ in the transformation  and simplify we get 
$w=\frac{z+2/i}{z/2+1/2} $.
And hence $w= \frac{2z-4i}{z+1}$.

Comment: And if u encounter with infinity jus don't worry ..use the concept of limits as we do in calculus replace infinity wid n and then take the limit n tends to infinity ...I hope it will help

Comment: Very good advice!